# stack vs queuing?

Tags: php, stack, queue

hello im still a student and im a bit confused about stacking and queuing ?
first question is,

1. what is the main diffrence between them two ?
2. btw there is circular queuing beside normal queuing how about that ? how do they work ? is there any different ways to queuing?
3. im useing php, is there a simple ( very simple or easy to read ) sample code that i can learn on ( links are okay too. )?
4. there is pop, push and etc ( stacking and queuing ), is there anything like that in php ?

Thank you very much for looking in.

Comment: I appreciate that you are a student, but you should really be able to trivially search and find answers to these questions.

Comment: @noon - maybe he has, but he's already askied over 30 questions on StackOverflow so he must trust the quality of answers given.

Comment: @kev thanks :) stack just give me excellent answers with less time. its getting addicting :(. anyway really quality matters not just that, its a community + wiki.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1: While with stacks the insert/removal operations both work on the same end of the data structure (top)

[image]

with queues the insertion takes place at one end (rear) and the removal at the other end (front).

[image]

(Both images are from the respective wikipedia entries)

2: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

3: and 4: see [SplStack](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.splstack.php) and [SplQueue](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.splqueue.php)

Answer (score 7):

In php you would use an array() to hold your data for both stacks and queues and use the array_* functions to manipulate them. Take a look at [array functions at php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)

You have

- array_push - put a new element at end of array
- array_pop - remove an element from end of array
- array_shift - remove an element from the beginning of array
- array_unshift - put a new element onto the beginning of array.
- For a stack you'd use array_push and array_pop
- For a queue you'd use array_push and array_shift

A circular buffer I would implement as a standalone object.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you are being steered towards the difference between first-in first-out and last-in first-out queues. A stack is the former, and a circular queue is an efficient implementation of the latter.

1. A [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29) is a LIFO (last in, first out) queue.
2. You can have a [circular queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) - these were most common on communication interface buffers as they had limited memory with data coming in asynchronously and the data being read by the CPU at different times.
3. You can create queues in any language if you know your language well.
4. The [php website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) offers a lot of documentation.

Answer (score 2):

A [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29) adds and removes items from the same end.

A [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29) adds items to the back and removes items from the front (like a line in a bank.)

There's an [article about them both](http://www.blogternals.com/2009/06/16/php-stack-andqueue/) that explains in detail with code samples.

A [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) has limited space and keeps adding items in a circular fashion overwriting the ones at the end.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php

You can look at the example code there

Answer (score 0):

This is only an answer for the 1st question, and the post is very old, but still wanted to share, because i like this image even though test tubes are usually for liquids :)

[image: queue vs stack]

Answer (score 0):

Stack is a DS in which elements can be inserted and deleted from only one side. It follows the principle of LIFO, which is last in first out. Just imagine a stack of books. You can only pick out that book which you placed last, i.e. the one at the top of the stack.

Queue is a DS in which elements can be inserted from one side and deleted from the other. It follows the principle of FIFO; first in first out. Just imagine a line at a fast food joint, the person who stood first shall be served first.

Circular queue is a special type of queue in which the first and last element are connected. The modification ensures that no empty space remains in the queue, and that each is utilized.

This is great resource for PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php